# combine the veactor into the dataframe with different row length

Tags: r

I have a vector which named as x. x has 18332 elements , which means 18332 rows.
I want to merge x into "y", which is the data frame, and has 13857 rows. I would like to know how to combine y and x with different row lengths. I tried the function"rbind.fill" in the plyr package, but it doesn't work. Also, I used another function"data.frame.na" in  the qpcR package, but it always showed "Error: could not find function "cbind.na".

For example,
`x=c(1:5)`
`ID=c(1:10`
`ID=Gender=c("F","F","M","M","F","M","F","M","M","M")`
`y=data.frame(ID,Gender)`

I would like to combine the vector x and the data frame y.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example, otherwise you will unlikely get any help and your question will be probably closed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a quick example for using rbind.fill() . rbind.fill() should be the solution for your problem given my understanding.  rbind.fill only works for data frames. So you might well convert the vector to data.frame with as.data.frame() function.

```
library(plyr)
x<-as.data.frame(1:10)
y<-as.data.frame(20:50)

z<-rbind.fill(x,y)
```

The result will be

```
   1:10 20:50
1     1    NA
2     2    NA
3     3    NA
4     4    NA
5     5    NA
6     6    NA
7     7    NA
8     8    NA
9     9    NA
10   10    NA
11   NA    20
12   NA    21
13   NA    22
14   NA    23
15   NA    24
16   NA    25
17   NA    26
18   NA    27
19   NA    28
20   NA    29
21   NA    30
22   NA    31
23   NA    32
24   NA    33
25   NA    34
26   NA    35
27   NA    36
28   NA    37
29   NA    38
30   NA    39
31   NA    40
32   NA    41
33   NA    42
34   NA    43
35   NA    44
36   NA    45
37   NA    46
38   NA    47
39   NA    48
40   NA    49
41   NA    50
```